# Code Igniter saving Model Object and Merging POST values to the Model Object

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, cron

I'm creating a form in CI that will send notification to various users,  when the form is submitted it will fetch the phone numbers of the registered user and send SMS notification into it.

When fetching data, I got this model object

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [phone] => +1234567488
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [phone] => +1254345888
            ) 

       )
```

I have cases where the unique phone numbers being fetch is is 15k rows, looping thru that 15k records is not a good idea as it will most likely create a memory error. What i have in mind is, Ill only send few notifications on submit of the form but store the remaining records in the my cron table. My cron table has the following fields:

> - id
> - phone
> - email
> - message (content is from the submitted form)

My Questions are:

1. Is it possible to update the model object to have the values from the POST, basically merge POST Values to model Object. Example:

   ```
   Array (
       [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [phone] => +1234567488
               [email] => ''
               [message] => 'Test here'

           )
       [1] => stdClass Object
           (
               [phone] => +1254345888
               [email] => ''
               [message] => 'Test here'
           ) 

      )
   ```

   I've added the email and message in the array. Is that possible? If yes, how? I tried this code below to merge it,

   $objT = $this->testModel()->getAllphone()->result() 
   $objT->email =''; 
   $objT->message = $_POST['message']; 
   $obt->save();

But it says, it was not successfull,  I got  this message "Attempt to assign property of non-object"

2. I have read in the CI documentation, that its possible to insert multiple rows, you can pass an array or object. Am I right that it will not work on CI model object? I have tried it and got some error What shall I do to make the saving of the remaining records work without extracting data to save execution time on loops.

This was my code for saving record

```
$this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $obj );
```

I know I can achieve all what I need by extracting the model object but I can't just extract it specially on records that has huge data like in my testing, its 15k users.

3. Is it possible also to get only the phone numbers in the  model object without using "for loop " and  "extracting" it to minimize looping.

Comment: Could you give more details about what are you doing? Please insert some more code to make it more clearly. I just understood a little about what you posted here.

Comment: @user2853290, I have a form that will notify users based on the inputted values in the form. In some cases, if there are too many data being fetch it will get page time out. To fix that issue, I wanted to have a batch notification sending which will be trigger in the cron. Eventually, I wanted to save all users that was fetch in my batch notification sending table